# ionic 3 different layout for mobile and tab

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

If i have a specific page(say list of recipes) which has a different design for mobile and tab Eg. List on a mobile, grid on a tab.
How do I design the layout in ionic? Do I have to make two different html files?

Comment: You are able to check the platform the app is running on - [info here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/). From there you can determine if the user is on a tablet or mobile phone and apply platform style specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the app is running on mobile or tablet in your ts file like:

```
this.isTabletOrIpad = this.platform.is('tablet') || this.platform.is('ipad');
```

Then you can use this variable in your html to design layout for tab and mobile -

```
<ion-list *ngIf="!isTabletOrIpad">
        ...
</ion-list>

<ion-grid *ngIf="isTabletOrIpad">
        ...
</ion-grid>
```

Additionally, we can use Media queries in scss file to style the layout for tab or phone based on screen size:

```
/* Larger than a phone */
@media (min-width: 567px) {
.postTime {
        background: #112112;
    }
}

/* Small devices such as phone */
@media (max-width: 567px) {
.postTime {
        background: #AFAFAF;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ionic also provides showWhen option to display according to platform or orientation.

```
<div showWhen="android">
 I am visible on Android!
</div>

<div showWhen="ios">
 I am visible on iOS!
</div>

<div showWhen="android,ios">
 I am visible on Android and iOS!
</div>

<div showWhen="portrait">
 I am visible on Portrait!
</div>

<div showWhen="landscape">
 I am visible on Landscape!
</div>
```

Refer this link- http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/show-hide-when/ShowWhen/